# How to Use Limit Query in php mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

**Frist Member database value:-**

```
 member_id = 1;
 member_no= 001;
 status = '2';
```

**2nd Member database value**

```
 member_id = 2;
 member_no= 002;
 status = '1';
```

**3rd Member database value**

```
member_id = 3;
member_no= 003;
status = '2';
```

**My Php Query**

```
$select_query_sender = "select * from member where status='1' ORDER BY member_id ASC LIMIT 1";
   $run_sender = mysqli_query($con,$select_query_sender);
   while ($row_sender = mysqli_fetch_array($run_sender)) {        
    $member_no_sender = $row_sender['member_no'];
    echo $member_no_sender;    }
```

I try to Retrive Status 1 Member list using Limit Query, I except Output to **member_no= 002;** but output nothing to show, What i missing Please Help Any one.

Comment: You're missing error reporting https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053424/how-do-i-get-php-errors-to-display

Answer (score 1):

Your code is ok , but check if your query is fetching any row from db.

```
 $select_query_sender = "select * from member where status='1' ORDER BY 

 member_id ASC LIMIT 1";

 $run_sender = mysqli_query($con,$select_query_sender);

 if($run_sender->num_rows > 0 ){

    while ($row_sender = mysqli_fetch_array($run_sender)) {  

        echo $row_sender['member_no']; // echo member_no
   }

 }else{
   echo "no row";
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try...

```
$select_query_sender = "select * from member where status='1' ORDER BY member_id ASC LIMIT 1";
$run_sender = mysqli_query($con,$select_query_sender);
$row_sender = mysqli_fetch_object($run_sender);
echo $row_sender->member_no ;
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/349538) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made. Please comment your changes to the original code at least.